# web2py create a field that is a list of floats

Tags: web2py

Im defining a table in web2py that contain some of the following fields:

```
Field('frequency_range_start', 'float', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(0,1000000000)], label="Frequency Start (kHz)", represent=lambda value, row:__represent_kHz(value)),
Field('frequency_range_end', 'float',   requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(0,1000000000)], label="Frequency End (kHz)", represent=lambda value, row:__represent_kHz(value)),
Field('channel_size', 'list:string',    requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(0,1000000000)], label="Channel Sizes (kHz)", represent=lambda value, row:__represent_kHz_list(float(value))),
```

I need *channel_size* to be a list of float values. I also need validation on the form - which the **requires** label takes care of in the two fields above...

Q: How can I create this Field so that it validates on the form only float values?

I've looked at "the book" here http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Field-types

but it makes it sound like you can substitute any type--> list:...

perhaps I can use a regex somewhere to have a check for only numbers that may or may not be real numbers

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no need for the `IS_NOT_EMPTY` validators, as the subsequent validators you are using already require non-empty values.

With `list:` fields, you can use the [`IS_LIST_OF`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Special-type-validators) validator. Even though you are storing the floats as strings, you can use the `IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE` validator, as it passes the values to `float()`.

Note, to make it easier to work with the values once you select them, you can specify a `filter_out` function to convert from a list of strings to a list of floats:

```
Field('channel_size', 'list:string',
      requires=IS_LIST_OF(IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(0, 1000000000), minimum=1),
      filter_out=lambda floats: [float(f) for f in floats],
      ...)
```

The above will require at least one float value to be entered and will reject any non-float strings. When you select data from the field, the list of strings will automatically be converted to a list of floats.

Note, you can also create a [custom field type](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Custom-Field-types--experimental-) to handle field types not supported by the DAL (i.e., you could create your own `list:float` custom field type).